# React this.state undefined in rowGetter using ReactDataGrid

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and attempting to get the React Data Grid working with some test data - Why would I be getting an error in the rowGetter function that this.state is undefined? I can't find an example that works anywhere.

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';

class FilterGrid extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    columns: PropTypes.array,
    rows: PropTypes.array
  };

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      columns: [],
      rows: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      rows: [
        {key: 'd1', lname: 'Doe', quantity: 3},
        {key: 'd2', lname: 'Simmons', quantity: 97},
        {key: 'd3', lname: 'Walters', quantity: 6}
      ],
      columns: [
        {name: "Quantity", key: "quantity"},
        {name: "Last Name", key: "lname"}
      ]
    }));
  }

  rowGetter(i) {
    return this.state.rows[i];
  }

  render() {
    return  (<ReactDataGrid
      columns={this.state.columns}
      rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
      rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
      minHeight={500} />);
  }
}

export default FilterGrid;
```

Comment: As I know, we have to declare new state using getInitializeState() function before accessing any state of class.

Answer (score 3):

Because you forgot to bind the `rowGetter`, bind it in the constructor:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      columns: [],
      rows: []
    }
    this.rowGetter = this.rowGetter.bind(this);     //here
}
```

As per **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)**:

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In
>   JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
>   bind this.methodName and pass it to event, **this will be undefined**
>   when the function is actually called. This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of [how functions work in JavaScript](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/).

Answer (score 2):

You've got to `bind` the callback or you don't have access to `this`:

```
render() {
    return  (<ReactDataGrid
      columns={this.state.columns}
      rowGetter={this.rowGetter.bind(this)}
      rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
      minHeight={500} />);
  }
```

However, binding like this will re-bind each time the `render` is called.  It is better to bind in the constructor or make an arrow function method:

constructor:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      columns: [],
      rows: []
    }

    this.rowGetter = this.rowGetter.bind(this);
  }
```

arrow function:

```
  rowGetter = (i) => {
    return this.state.rows[i];
  }
```

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you! - Been pulling hair out all morning

Comment: binding method inside render is not a good idea as per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html): *The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the component renders.*